# Calculate column based on previous value of the same calculated column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

Below is the sample data:

| Month | Payment Made | Payment Required | payment Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 200 | 190 | 190 |
| 3 | 500 | 190 | 190 |
| 4 | 0 | 190 | 190 |
| 5 | 0 | 190 | 380 |
| 6 | 200 | 190 | 570 |
| 7 | 200 | 190 | 560 |

Here, Payment due is calculated as -

```
if 
    ('payment made' previous month < 'Payment due' previous month) 
then 
    'payment due' previous month + 'Payment required' current month - 'Payment made' previous month
else
    'Payment required' current month
END if
```

---

I know that i can use 'Lag' to get the previous month's value of payment made, but how do i do it for the calculated column - Payment Due?

Comment: add the queries you've tried so far in the question, it'll make users easier to find a solution for you

Comment: please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question and make a [mre]

Comment: Create a view instead.

Comment: @jarlh can you please help with the code. Not sure how the view will help.

Answer (score 0):

CTE with recursion might work assuming months start from 1

```
with recursive cte 
as (
  select month, payment_made, payment_required, 0 payment_due
  from data
  where month = 1
  union
  select b.month, b.payment_made, b.payment_required, (
    case when a.payment_made < a.payment_due
       then a.payment_due + b.payment_required - a.payment_made
       else b.payment_required
       end
  ) 
  from cte a
  join data b on a.month + 1 = b.month
)
select * from cte
```

or recursion on row_number

```
with recursive 
seq as ( 
  select *, row_number() over(order by month) rn
  from data
),
cte as (
  select seq.rn, seq.month, seq.payment_made, seq.payment_required, seq.payment_required payment_due
  from seq
  where seq.rn = 1
  union
  select b.rn, b.month, b.payment_made, b.payment_required, (
    case when a.payment_made < a.payment_due
       then a.payment_due + b.payment_required - a.payment_made
       else b.payment_required
       end
  ) 
  from cte a
  join seq b on a.rn + 1 = b.rn
)
select * from cte
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40b4da5924ea279d6c3d3c1a0e0cb1cd

Answer (score 0):

This would work because month on  your exampole  starts with1 1 and increase by one, if the data isn't  that smooth, you must change the subquery in the update to fit better

> ```
> CREATE TABLE payments (
>   `Month` INTEGER,
>   `Payment Made` INTEGER,
>   `Payment Required` INTEGER,
>   `payment Due` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO payments
>   (`Month`, `Payment Made`, `Payment Required`, `payment Due`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '0', '0', '0'),
>   ('2', '200', '190', '190'),
>   ('3', '500', '190', '190'),
>   ('4', '0', '190', '190'),
>   ('5', '0', '190', '380'),
>   ('6', '200', '190', '570'),
>   ('7', '200', '190', '560');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE payments as pay1 
> ,
> (SELECT 
> p2.`Month`,
> if 
>     (p1.`Payment Made`  < p1.`payment Due`, 
>
>     p1.`payment Due` + p2.`Payment Made` - p1.`Payment Made`
> ,
>     p2.`Payment Required`
> ) payment_due
> FROM payments p1 INNER JOIN payments p2 ON p2.`Month` = p1.`Month` + 1) pay2 
> SET pay1.`payment Due` = pay2.payment_due
> WHERE pay1.`Month` = pay2.`Month`
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM payments
> ```
>
> ```
> Month | Payment Made | Payment Required | payment Due
> ----: | -----------: | ---------------: | ----------:
>     1 |            0 |                0 |           0
>     2 |          200 |              190 |         190
>     3 |          500 |              190 |         190
>     4 |            0 |              190 |         190
>     5 |            0 |              190 |         190
>     6 |          200 |              190 |         580
>     7 |          200 |              190 |         570
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c093ba095b0cee6a12b4a8868a4a3ef3)*